# Keras ANN Trained Model's Accuracy change on prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, keras

I have trained an ANN Binary classifier using Keras. It gives 90% accuracy. 
After testing when I predict same data again but pass only one class then accuracy decreases to 40%. 
I have figured out that if I pass mixed classes while predicting then it will give me around 90%  accuracy and if I pass data points of only one class then accuracy decreases .As I increase the data points of other class as well then accuracy increases.
Long in short.
CASE 1:
100 samples from class 0,
100 sample from class 1,
on predicting using trained model Accuracy = 90%

CASE 2:
Same 100 samples from class 0 passes to same trained Models give me 40% accuracy.
Why accuracy changes ?

EDIT: I'm performing Standardization before predicting every time which effects the predictions. How to handle this case?
Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved if we use same Mean and Standard Deviation which used for standardization of training samples.